# why I can't bind function with rvalue args like this?

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue-reference, stdbind, stdmove

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

template<typename Func, typename... Args>
void do_task(Func &func, Args &&...args)
{
    auto f = bind(func, forward<Args>(args)...);
    f();
}

int main()
{
    string name = "hello";
    auto test_func = [](string name, string &&arg1, string &&arg2) -> void {
        cout << name << " " << arg1 << " " << arg2 << endl;
    };

    // do_task(test_func,"test_one", "hello", string("world"));     // compile error
    // do_task(test_func, "test_tww", std::move(name), "world");    // compile error
    do_task(test_func, "test_three", "hello", "world"); // compile ok
    return 0;
}
```

In my understanding, `string("word")` and `std::move(name)` both have the right value, but test_one and test_tww can't compile. (g++ (GCC) 12.1.1 20220730)

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: If you'd use a new fangled *lambda* instead of an old fashioned *bind*, you could have do_task `[&]{ func(forward<Args>(args)...); }();`

Comment: TL:DR of the dupes: the bound function can be called multiple times.  Because of that `bind` always passes the stored value as an lvalue.  if it was an rvalue it could be moved from making any subsequent calls to the functor returned from `bind` invalid.